# Regex Game - Replace each word except specific ones by a variable number of characters

Tags: regex

**Hey there, you Regex Lovers !**

I'm quite in Regex, these times and had a purely theorical problem. To put it simple, I will present it as a game.
**The game :**
Let's say you have a list of words separated by spaces.
What I call a word is as they are defined by regular expressions : `[a-zA-Z_0-9]+` (There is no empty word here)
Example of list :
`Horse Banana Joker RoXx0r A_Long_Word Joker 1337`
What I want you to do is replace each word except *Joker* by a number of *$* equal to the number of character of the matched word.
With our previous list we would obtain :
`$$$$$ $$$$$$ Joker $$$$$$ $$$$$$$$$$$ Joker $$$$`
**In fewer words :** *I want a regex that matches each character that does not belong to the word "Joker"* (In the string, I mean, not that compose the word Joker)
While it is not easy, it's not impossible (I have my own regex for that). That's why I will set some rules.
**The rules :**

- It must be done with only 1 regex
- I will not accept any regex that works only in specific languages
- I will still accept most common features like Conditionals, Lookarounds, etc... even if some languages can't read them
- No recursion allowed *(but if you have a working recursive one, post it, just for the beauty of the regex ^^)*
- The regex must be optimized for performance
- If your regex *matches* (get it ? ;) ) these rules but does not satisfy me, I will feel free to add some more rules

**Added rules :**

- None

To help you out, here are some strings on which the regex **must** work :
`Horse Banana Joker RoXx0r A_Long_Word Joker 1337 Joke Poker Joker Jokers`
Must return after replacement :
`$$$$$ $$$$$$ Joker $$$$$$ $$$$$$$$$$$ Joker $$$$ $$$$ $$$$$ Joker $$$$$$`
`Joker Joker Joker`
Must return after replacement :
`Joker Joker Joker`

Again, **solving the problem is not the goal here**, I want to see different solutions, and more importantly I want to see the best ones !

---

**Solutions :**
A very elegant one by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) :
 
`(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\S)(?!Joker(?:\s|$)))\S` (replace : `$`)
[See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791053/7963408)
However the \G take the fun out of the problem and does not work in every language, so I can't accept it unless is is possible to create a custom delimiter that is equivalent to \G
Almost accepted answer also by [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) :
`((?:\s+|\bJoker\b)*)\S((?:\s+Joker)*\s*$)?` (replace : `$1$$2`)
[See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791053/7963408)
Does not work when there are only Joker words in the string
A similar solution by [ClasG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064981/clasg) :
`(\bJoker[^\w]+)\w|\w([^\w]+Joker\b)|\w` (replace : `$1$$2`)
[See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43800093/7963408)
Does not work when there are only Joker words in the string
Another one by [ClasG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064981/clasg) :
`[^Joker\s]|(?<!\b)J|J(?!oker\b)|(?<!\bJ)o|o(?!ker\b)|(?<!\bJo)k|k(?!er\b)|(?<!\bJok)e|e(?!r\b)|(?<!\bJoke)r|r(?!\b)` (replace : `$`)
[See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43803650/7963408)
Not very efficient, though, but it's another way of seeing things ;)
I came up with a similar regex after reading the comment of Rahul below :
`(?(?<=\b|\bJ|\bJo|\bJok|\bJoke|\bJoker)(?!(?:Joke|oke|ke|e|)r\b)\w|\w)` (replace `$`)
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hwNDDH/1)
It is also inefficient, but use the same lookaround list thing :)

Here is my first solution :
I use a trick that might be considered as cheating, but I don't because it would not alter the functions you use to replace characters. You just have to add a '$' at the end of the string before replacing charactes into it.
So instead of something like :
`string = replace(string, regex, '$1$2')`
We would have :
`string = replace(string+'$', regex, '$1$2')`
So here is the regex :
`(\bJoker\b)|.$|\w(?=.*(\$))` (replace : `$1$2`)
[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/BGblXE/1)
This should work with all languages except those not supporting lookaheads (they are rather rare)
**Keep posting new regex if you find ones, I want to see more ways to do it ! :)**

Comment: Have you heard of this Stack site? You may want to post here if you don't get desired answers: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wait, RoXx0r has a 0 so it's not a word... so words include 0-9?

Comment: I already defined what a word is in this context just a few lines before ;)

Comment: You define it as [a-zA-Z_]+, which means RoXx0r  and 1337 are not words, but in your example, they are $ out anyways =P

Comment: Oh my bad, I just missed it. It's edited ! :)

Comment: Let me guess. Your solution consists of a list of lookahead and lookbehind in alteration ?

Comment: Not at all. It is based on an alternation yes. However i use only 1 lookahead

Comment: But I will look for a solution based on a list of lookarounds, just for fun :)

Comment: About the pattern with a conditional, it doesn't work with a word like `Jker` or `Jer` because each branch of the lookbehind is not associated with a specific branch of your lookahead. You can write it this way and remove the conditional: https://regex101.com/r/WNDkUv/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PCRE/Perl/Ruby/Java/.net

find:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|(?<!\S)(?!Joker(?!\S)))\S
```

replace:

```
$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3WQdi/1)

pattern details:

```
(?:
    \G (?!^) # contigous to a previous match (but not at the start of the string)
  |        # OR
    (?<!\S)  # not preceded by a non white-space
    (?!Joker(?!\S)) # not followed by the forbidden word
)
\S   # a non-whitespace character
```

If your words are only composed of word characters, you can simplify the pattern playing with word and non-word boundaries: `(?:\G\B|\b(?!Joker\b))\w`

---

Other way (PCRE/Perl): without the `\G` feature and with the backtracking control verb `(*SKIP)` (need less steps):

```
\s*(?:Joker(?:\s+|$))*(*SKIP)\K.
```

To be clear `(*SKIP)` is only useful when the string ends with the forbidden word or a whitespace. You can also replace it with `(*COMMIT)`.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3WQdi/5)

or:

```
\bJoker\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\S
```

and with pypi python regex module (that has a word boundary for the start and one for the end of a word):

```
\mJoker\M(*SKIP)(*F)|\S
```

---

A one that works with Javascript *(if there's something to replace only)*:

find:

```
((?:\s+|\bJoker\b)*)\S((?:\s+Joker)*\s*$)?
```

replace: *(backreference to group1, escaped $, backreference to group2)*

```
$1$$$2
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hdnSXk/1)

---

An other Javascript version that uses the y flag *(that forces the matches to be contigous)*, but unfortunately this one isn't supported by Internet Explorer, Safari and mobile browsers except Firefox mobile:

```
var strs = ['Horse Banana Joker RoXx0r A_Long_Word Joker 1337 Joke Poker Joker', 'Joker Joker Joker'];

strs.forEach(function (s) {
    console.log(s.replace(/(?=((?:\s+|\bJoker\b)*))\1./gy, '$1$$'));
});
```

The `(?=(...))\1` emulates an atomic group (that forbids backtracking).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the \G anchor, this is nice ! However some important languages (like Java, python) can't use it properly, so it's not what i'm looking for. Is here a way to code a custom anchor equivalent to \G ?

Comment: @Pharaoh: yes I just see it. I was hypnotised by Kadhja Bonet voice.

Comment: (*SKIP) and \K not allowed, too specific, sorry. I'll add them to the rules ;)

Comment: Actually, I won't add any rule, as it's already specified with the second rule ^^ And for (*COMMIT) it's the exact same problem !

Comment: @Gawil: I added a Javascript version.

Comment: This one is exactly the kind of regex I am looking for, very nice ! I'll mark your answer as accepted a bit later, I'm waiting for potential other answers :)

Comment: @Gawil: Definitely, `\1$\2` replacement string won't work in JS. Use `"$1$$$2"`.

Comment: The javascript solution doesn't work for `Joker Joker Joker`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew 7 : Indeed, it's also cleaner for other languages

Comment: @degant: indeed, but I doubt there's a regex only javascript version that works with nothing to replace. *(since there's no way to know what has been matched before, no lookbehind, no `\G` feature)*

Comment: @degant : Oh yeah, didn't notice that ! More generally, it does not work with any string ending with any sequence of 2 or more Joker words.

Comment: @Gawil: I edited it to make it works with any number of forbidden words at the end, however it always doesn't work when there's nothing to replace, and I doubt it is possible to build a pattern able to do that in Javascript.

Comment: Yes I'm working on it but can't find anything either. The best I did is obtaining the correct replaced string with the J of the last Joker replaced by $. But still, you're answer is really good, as I allowed lookarounds because I didn't think it was possible otherwise ^^

Comment: @Gawil: I added a version that uses the y flag, but this one isn't widely supported.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Well, I can't totally reject it, but the y flag is the same as the \G anchor, it destroys the interest of the problem. Plus it's specific to javascript, if i'm correct. I prefer your second answer ^^

Comment: @Gawil: You start with the postulate that there are patterns that work with every regex engines. This postulate is wrong. Regex engines are different. This doesn't make sense to allow conditionals (that aren't available in Python and Javascript) and to forbid the `\G` feature at the same time. If you think that the `\G` feature destroys the interest of the problem, you can also deduce yourself that your problem hadn't so much interest. Whatever I'm waiting for your "ulgy" pattern that is supposed to work with Javascript isn't it?.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : I don't want to debate here whether or not my problem is interesting. It's just that using the \G makes it trivial, and not using \G doesn't. That's why I prefer regex without it ;)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : Again, as I said multiple times, solving the problem is not what I am interested in, It's the way of solving it that I'm looking for. By the way, I've added my regex.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here we go again ;) This time with a complete solution, that should work in most regex flavors (except JS). It's not very flexible, but it works:

```
[^Joker\s]|(?<!\b)J|J(?!oker\b)|(?<!\bJ)o|o(?!ker\b)|(?<!\bJo)k|k(?!er\b)|(?<!\bJok)e|e(?!r\b)|(?<!\bJoke)r|r(?!\b)
```

or more readable

```
[^Joker\s] # Test for any character not belonging to the word Joker
|
(?<!\b)J|J(?!oker\b) # Test for J not belonging to the word Joker
|
(?<!\bJ)o|o(?!ker\b) # Test for o not belonging to the word Joker
|
(?<!\bJo)k|k(?!er\b) # Test for k not belonging to the word Joker
|
(?<!\bJok)e|e(?!r\b) # Test for e not belonging to the word Joker
|
(?<!\bJoke)r|r(?!\b) # Test for r not belonging to the word Joker
```

It matches the characters from the word `Joker` separately, making sure they're **not** in that word, using look-behinds and look-aheads. Alternatively it matches all letters not in the word at all.

Replacing the matches with `$` does the job.

[Here it is at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XysCJA/4).

**Edit**

Changed the order of the test to make it much more efficient. (From >1600 to ~ 1100 steps.)

Comment: Hey, I just found a similar solution about an hour ago after reading a comment of Rahul ^^ Since you posted it, I'll post my version too :)

Comment: I really don't like this kind of regex, though, as it feels like there are so many repetitions. Plus, complexity must be pretty explosive... My guess is exponential. But it's a solution that deserve a look !

Answer (score 1):

Can't really say why, but I wanted to see if I could make it without look-arounds. This is what I ended up with:

```
(\bJoker[^\w]+)\w|\w([^\w]+Joker\b)|\w
```

Substituting that with `$1$$2` should do the trick.

It has one limitation though (that I thought of). It wont handle `Joker` as a single word on the line :(. That's because the logic behind it is...

It matches the word `Joker` in two alternations - either with a letter following it, or preceding it. In both cases separating the word from the letter by *non letters* (spaces). There is a third alternative as well - a single letter. If none of the two first matches, this will find non Joker-related letters.
In the first two cases, the word plus adjacent spaces (non-letters) get captured into a group (`Joker`-space). Same goes for second alternative, but in reversed order (space-`Joker`). The third alternative doesn't capture anything . it just matches a letter.

Replacing the complete match with `$1$$2` (note the literal `$` in the middle) either inserts the word `Joker` plus spaces (if the first alternation matched) followed by a `$`.
If the first didn't match, but the second did, the inserted replacement would be the `$` plus captured spaces followed by `Joker`.
If none of the two first matched, nothing is captured, and the only thing inserted will be the sole `$`, replacing whatever letter matched.

[See it here at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/iDmeR1/1/)

**Edit:**

Just noticed that Casimir et Hippolyte has a version at the end that's similar to mine. They're not identical though, so I'll leave my answer here for now ;)

Comment: Nice one too, a bit similar to the second one of Casimir et Hippolyte, but still another way to see it. It faces the same problem though, as it can't handle any string composed of forbidden words only.